# How do I install a flutter in VS code with an emulator without Android Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, flutter

Though I have been working on Android studio for flutter as a new bee, now I am thinking to move in VScode and want to use blue stake like an emulator. Now I want to know is there any way of developing flutter in VScode without installing android studio??

Comment: You can use VSCode without AS but you need to install the Android SDK the way AS installs it if you want to do Android development. If you only target iOS you shouldn't need any Android stuff (but there might be a bug that causes a failure if Android SDK is not available - not sure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, installing Android Studio is the supported way to get all the bits you need:

https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#system-requirements

> Flutter relies on a full installation of Android Studio to supply its Android platform dependencies. However, you can write your Flutter apps in a number of editors; a later step will discuss that.

It is possible to make things work without (by installing bits of the SDK, Gradle, etc. manually, and ensuring they're on PATH or in relevant env variables) but it's more complicated. I (the author of the Dart/Flutter VS Code plugins) used to run without Android Studio but things like upgrading the Android SDK are much simpler with Android Studio (as far as I can tell, the GUI for updating the SDK was seemingly moved from the SDK into Android Studio).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this. But you can download the SDK individually without downloading the Android Studio.

Here is the link: https://developer.android.com/studio/
Go to

> Command line tools only

section and Download the respected version according to your OS.